# Delegate BadStartNameChar Exception

Tags: c#, caching, delegates

I am trying this code

```
return GlavCacheManagement.GetCache("cachekey",15, () => 
{ 
    var list=_repo.GetByLang(IsActiveOrAccepted.Active); 
    return (currentLangId>0 ? 
    list.Where(x => x.LangId== currentLangId) : list).ToList(); 
});
```

I am chaching my return value.Here is my GlavCacheManagement class method

```
public static T GetCache<T>(string key, int h, Func<T> del) where T:class 
{ 
    if (FrSettings.Settings.IsGlavCacheActive)
    {
        return AppServices.Cache.Get<T>(key, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(h),del);
    } 

    return del.Invoke(); 
}
```

I am getting the exception because of my delegate name.

Delegate FullName:

> Sport.DataAccess.Services.UserDestekHedefServices+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0()

Delegate Name:

```
<GetActiveHedefOfUser>b__0
```

**Stacktrace**: System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)

**Exception** : System.Xml.XmlException, Xml_BadStartNameChar 0x3C can not start with char '<' for method name

My code lang is c# and I am getting this exception [Glav.CacheAdapter](https://github.com/glav/Glav.CacheAdapter) package

My Project Name:Sport.DataAccess,

My Folder Name:Services,

Class Name:UserDestekHedefServices,

My _repo Property:

```
private readonly IUserDestekHedefRepository _repo;
```

Comment: Why on earth do you name anything in C# this way? Could you rename it?

Comment: @Nikolaus Sport.DataAccess is my project name, Services is my folder name, UserDestekHedefServices is my class name.

Comment: Why your delegate‘s name starts with <?

Comment: Yes this is the problem I dont know I am debugging at GetCache<T> method and looking the delegate info.Olaa fullname and name is like this.

Comment: You could try to define your delegate and use the defined one, instead of using an anonymous Function. But I don’t know, whether your problem is caused in the class-method or outside.

Comment: @Nikolaus I have now tried and did not working.

Comment: I‘m sorry that I can’t help you.